# Im trying to add two foreign keys on the same table and it doesn't work

Tags: sql

I have noticed that when I use `I` on a column the problems go away but when i click on go, the only errors that comes is a "Cannot add foreign key constraint" message.

error messages :

[image: error messages]

Comment: Typo : LOACTION instead of LOCATION

Comment: As an aside - are you sure you want two *separate* foreign keys rather than a composite one? Your current design means that the latitude and longitude may be references to two *completely separate* rows within `LOCATION`.

Comment: I can't read that tiny picture text...

Comment: Also, your "Longitude" FK is referencing the "Latitude" column.

Comment: I would like the attributes to be composite but i wasnt sure if it work. I was copying and pasting my original to work out what the problem was and must have just let that go over my head.

Comment: In the future, when you add the SQL tag and the dialog appears that suggests you add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, **please don't ignore it**. Syntax and features vary widely between different DBMSs, and it's **highly relevant** to know which specific one you're using. (That's why that  dialog appears.)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you you have misspelled `LOCATION` in the first statement.

Comment: thanks, i probably wouldn't have seen that mistake

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled Location once and both of your foreign keys are referencing the same primary key.